# TSQL: What all factor to be consider while working on import, validate and insert functionality

Tags: sql-server

We have an import functionality wherein we import data from excel into sql server staging table and perform validation. This is an existing functionality and implemented like this:
1) User can download excel template to order gadgets in bulk. 
2) User can fill in single or multiple orders in excel sheet and upload the sheet into the application.
3) Using .net SqlBulkCopy feature, we copy the excel data into a staging table in sql server.
4) Now we copy these data into #tempTable and perform the validation on each record for the correctness per some standards and if found some error then respective error message is updated in one column of #tempTable.
5) After validation if all the records are validated successfully then we proceed for inserting these records in order and billing tables.

To perform above steps we have 3 SPs:
1) Get_Data(To copy data from staging table into #tempTable)
2) Validate_Date (To validate the data in #tempTable)
3) Insert_Data (To insert data into tables if all records are validated successfully)

The above SPs are not performing good as per business due to the implementation of Cursors and Dynamic queries which could be avoided.

Now we have to prepare an another import functionality from scratch for one of the new module considering performance an important factor. I have read many articles for using best practice in writing SP like avoid cursors as max as possible, use set nocount on etc.

Request you guys to please help me in recognizing other areas to be taken care while coding for such type of import functionality. For example:
1) Since the import data is going to be consumed from excel sheet, so do we need to consider the max number of rows upon which (we have to perform validation etc) should take care?? If so, please suggest how to handle the performance for validation and insertion for varying data like from limited to huge data records. Or if there is going only to have a limited amount of data then how to code to get maximum performance for such limited records.
2) Should we also consider concurrent access. Like multiple users can assess import functionality from different locations. I know that we can control concurrency using Transaction. Please suggest if there is any better method for the same.
etc

This is the first time i am working on such import functionality for performance improvement. Please suggest/share your experiences to be kept in mind from performance point while coding.

Comment: This type of question will be primarily opinion based, and it is entirely too long for a forum post, as such it is off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See,What ever you have written and what you think about doing is correct ?
like validation and refining data,avoid cursor etc.all your points are valid.
Most probably you do the validation work in front end itself(presentation layer itself).Or validation can be on two level.Basic validation(data type validation,not null check etc) in front end,then secondary validation (validation against DB).you do validation against db and insert work at one GO.

Secondly you think about transaction when multiple user trying to access same records.Here it is not that case.Here multiple user will upload there own records.
So you can avoid transaction because there is no chance of locking.
**Am I wrong ?**

Comment: Thanks @KumarHarsh really helpful.